# Cant get widget to keep its aspect ratio

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt-designer, aspect-ratio

I am making a program with Qtcreator (using qt designer too). 
I made some QSvgWidget buttons (What i wanted was a scalable image based button). They work but don't keep the aspect ratio of the image (aspect ratio needs to be 1:1).
I haven't been able to come up with a solution for this myself even after hours of trying.

I have tried:

```
QSizePolicy qsp(QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
qsp.setHeightForWidth(true);
ui->Widgetname->setSizePolicy(qsp);
```

But that doesn't work.

Some images of the problem:

---

Correct:

[image]

Incorrect:

[image]
[image]

---

I am new to working with Qt and coding.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I seemed to have overlooked this link in other posts about this (most reply's suggested setHeigthForWidth): http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/CS001309_-_Maintaining_square_form_for_a_widget_in_Qt I still am not sure why setHeightForWidth doesn't do the job. But this works well enough.